# asp.net not displaying a custom 404 page as configured

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404

in my web config I have:

```
<customErrors mode="On">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/error/404.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

http://localhost/meh <-- standard 404 is shown

http://localhost/meh.aspx <-- custom 404 is shown

http://localhost/error/404.aspx <-- the custom error page I want shown for *all* 404 errors

How do I have to setup my web.config to send all 404 to my custom error?

Thanks

Comment: Good question. I didn't realize that this was handled that way. It does seem odd because a 404 is a 404 regardless of the extension.

Comment: sounds like you'll have to configure it in IIS, as any non-.aspx extension would be handled by iis not the .net app pool running your application i think?

Comment: Jimmy: So I have to double my config settings, exactly, do everything is handled the same? That seems backwards to me. my understanding is web.config is the config for the site. when going to a page on a site that does not exist, shouldn't the sites config kick in and redirect to the 404 page?

Comment: No, only certain file extensions get handled by the ASP.NET Framework.  Otherwise IIS handles it.  Check my answer.

Comment: @justin the web.config if for .net based applications... IIS can also host ie. php, perl, java or whatever which doesn't use the web.config. This has changed in the newest versions of web.config where it now contains a system.webServer section, but as a thumbrule web.config is for an .net application, not the webserver itself.

Comment: @Pauli - the web application configured in IIS is pointing to my directory and setup as a .net application. So the .net application is running for that directory, and the config is telling it to use custom 404, but its not. the other virtual directory and site on the server is, hypothetically, setup for php, for that virtual dir i wouldn't expect it to use my web.config. Everything in my setup application's directory i would. Having to setup error pages for the same application in 2 places, thats what I think is non-intuitive and bad a design choice by microsoft.

Comment: @justin you don't setup the application in iis as a .net application, thats where you are wrong. All you tell IIS is that when it encounters an url with this or that extension, then execute it through .Net, and if it has this or that extension, then execute it as php. Remember, IIS (6 and before) was designed way back before .net even existed and as per design doesn't know about .net.

Comment: @Pauli - Under (server -> sites -> default web site -> folder) I have to right click and pick convert to application. When I do that I would expect everything in that folder to listen my web.config application settings, for everything in that folder... why should I have to change the error page settings in IIS for the same folder (that is now an application) when the application's web.conf told it already? 2 place, same thing = bad bad bad. IMO.

Comment: @justin you are still wrong. This is an IIS termonology called Application Pools, has nothing to do with .Net. Read more about it here http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/67e39bd8-317e-4cf6-b675-6431d4425248.mspx?mfr=true. You make the same mistake as so many other programmers, that they think IIS and asp.net are one and the same. THEY ARE NOT.

Comment: @Pauli - I'll admit I may be wrong about terminology, but the fact that I have to set the setting in 2 places to do the same thing is bad. The fact that I have to "Convert to Application" for it to run at all makes me believe that the directory as a whole is a asp.net application. These are assumptions, but i think they are logical assumptions. and i guess "so many other programmers" make the same assumptions as well. So setting a folder to be an ASP application doesn't make the whole folder an application. Good thing to remember - way counter intuitive, but good to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to configure this in IIS.  By default, only specific files will get routed through the ASP.NET framework... otherwise IIS will handle it.  [image]

Comment: Just for fun, what if I don't have access to IIS on my hosting server? I just want to config my site, with web.config, the site's config :)

Comment: Not sure what you would have to do.  You would either have to request the 404 page be changed, or request all request to come through ASP.NET.  I ran into this same issue awhile ago because I was trying to do URL Rewriting in WebForms, but it would not work unless I edited IIS.  This link was where I figured my problem it.  It's about URL rewriting, but it still applies: http://urlrewriter.net/index.php/support/installation/windows-server-2003

Comment: Thanks for the help, and on that note i have to say, I thought my opinion of microsoft couldn't get any worse.... it did. needing to configure the same feature in 2 places is just dumb

Comment: @Justing808: I agree.. Kind of.  It's a matter of what is handling the request.  Either they run everything through the .net processing engine (which would have non-obvious side effects) or they would have to let the IIS engine itself handle ones that were probably better of handled by an application.. (consider url rewriting).  It's a catch 22.

Comment: I agree.  I think it's handled properly by default.  No need for non-.NET pages to run through the .NET engine and incur the additional overhead.

Comment: @justin the web.config is only for your one single .net application, not for the webserver. If http://localhost/meh is not invoking your .net application, the web.config is never used. And there is no need to configure it 2 places. Just forget about 404 in web.config and make sure ONLY to configure it in the IIS manager. Then it will work for php, java and perl applications as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Application_Error event handler in the global.asax file to redirect the user to ~/error/meh.aspx

in global.asax

```
 protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      Response.Redirect("~/error/404.aspx");

 }
```

In your web.config, also add

```
  <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/error/404.aspx" />
```

Comment: This still only redirects for missing .aspx pages, not for _any_ missing file.  if the user types http://localhost/missing.html or http://localhost/missing.dnd or http://localhost/missing.pl or http://localhost/missing or http://localhost/missing.php I want it to go to the custom 404.

Comment: TheGeekYouNeed, i think you misunderstand my question. Please see my edit above. I can get the ASP engine to only show a 404 when the error initiated from a missing URL ending in .aspx but not when it ends in anything else.