# Not displaying 404 aspx page from site or server

Tags: asp.net, webforms, routes, iis-7.5

How can I force IIS and ASP.NET WebForms to go to our custom error page for an undefined routing?

I've reviewed the question [asp-net-not-displaying-a-custom-404-page-as-configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5185799/asp-net-not-displaying-a-custom-404-page-as-configured).

1. We are using IIS 7.5
2. ASP.NET 4.0
3. Web Forms

If we have a request for http://www.oursite.com/searches, and we don't have "searches" defined in our routing map. We're getting a blank page back from the request with a 404 Status. We have:

- Default 404 page at the server level
- Default 404 page at the website level
- Default error page defined in the web.config file

In our code, if throw an HTTPException of 404 we end up on our custom 404 page. If we request an ASPX page that doesn't exist we get our custom error page. If I add a default "catchall" routing for our site at the end of the routes, our cart process stops working.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

When you search like -  http://www.oursite.com/searches and it returns a blank page back from the request with a 404 Status. Its an http protocol error returning from IIS/Web Server. Your web config settings for custom error page will work only for .net framework exception. Configure your IIS to go to your custom error page that returns a 404 error.

[image]

[image]

[image]